# Start with 11th word until character '-' is found by using awk command in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have this text with white spaces

```
9   100%   361.7 tr  Back       976.0     0.0    2.8  Get      [FFF] DO SOMETHING HERE - 01
```

and I want to convert it to this

DO SOMETHING HERE

I tried with this:

```
awk 'match($0, "\.-") {print substr($0, 1, RSTART)}'
```

but it gives me something like this output:

```
9   100%   361.7 tr  Back       976.0     0.0    2.8  Get      [FFF] DO SOMETHING HERE
```

There is any ways to start with 11th word and stop until character '-' is found ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this?

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<11;i++)$i="";sub(/-.*$/,"");sub(/^ */,"")}7'
```

or **sed**:

```
sed -r 's/(\S+\s+){10}//;s/-.*$//'
```

in fact, **grep** can do that for you:

```
grep -Po '(\S+\s+){10}\K[^-]*'
```

your example:

```
kent$  grep -Po '(\S+\s+){10}\K[^-]*' <<<"9   100%   361.7 tr  Back       976.0     0.0    2.8  Get      [FFF] DO SOMETHING HERE - 01"
DO SOMETHING HERE
```

Comment: Thanks! first and second option working good. This is what i was looking for! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it without forking at all.

```
read _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ word <<< '9   100%   361.7 tr  Back       976.0     0.0    2.8  Get      [FFF] DO SOMETHING HERE - 01'
echo "${word%-*}"
```